# How to get the first day of week for a certain Locale / Country

Tags: java, date, calendar, locale

I need to get the first day of week for a certain Locale / Country.

I tried to find it using this code:

```
final Locale[] locales = new Locale[]{
        new Locale("en_GB"),
        new Locale("ru_RU"),
        new Locale("en_US"),                
        new Locale("es_ES"),
        new Locale("fr_FR"),        
        new Locale("iw_IL"),
        new Locale("he_IL")
};

for (final Locale locale : locales) {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    final int firstDayOfWeek = cal.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    System.out.println(firstDayOfWeek);
}
```

The result of this code is that all of these locales are retrieving '1' which is Sunday, and locales such `en_US` should return 2 which is Monday.

Comment: I would have expected Sunday for the USA, but Monday for UK and France.

Comment: The `Calendar` class is long outdated and was always poorly designed. You need `WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek()`.

Comment: This worked for me: `Locale.forLanguageTag("en-GB")` (note hyphen instead of underscore). Docs: [Creating a Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass in two arguments – **language & country**, separately – rather than your string with underscore. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html).

```
final Locale[] locales = new Locale[]{
        new Locale("en", "GB"),  // Pass language code, then country code, separately.
        new Locale("ru", "RU"),
        new Locale("en", "US"),
        new Locale("es", "ES"),
        new Locale("fr", "FR"),
        new Locale("iw", "IL"),
        new Locale("he", "IL")
    };
```

And then I would use Java8 to get the first day of the week:

```
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek();
System.out.println(firstDayOfWeek);
```

Output:

> MONDAY
>
> MONDAY
>
> SUNDAY
>
> MONDAY
>
> MONDAY
>
> SUNDAY
>
> SUNDAY

Comment: But how come that it's Sunday over US ?

Comment: The US week does start on Sunday. [Why does the week starts on Sunday in the USA?](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-week-starts-on-Sunday-in-the-USA)

Answer (score 5):

You have a mistake in initializing the `Locale`, you need to pass two arguments **language** and **country**. The single argument constructor is only for **language**.

For example for `Locale("en_GB")`, should be `Locale("en", "GB")`, and then the result will be 2.

BTW for `Locale("en", "US")` the result is 1 (Sunday).

Comment: Very correct answer. But better to stop using the outdated `Calendar` class. I can never remember whether it numbers the days from Sunday or Monday, nor whether from 0 or 1, so telling me the result is 2 for GB and 1 for US doesn’t really convince me unless I dig deep into the documentation to check what those numbers mean.